# Download excel file in current folder instead of "downloads"

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to download an excel file using Selenium in Python from a website
I need the file to be downloaded in the current folder instead of "download"

but it is not working, it is downloading it in the downloads folder

```
mime_types = [
    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
]
options = Options()
options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
options.set_preference("browser.download.dir","./")
options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", ",".join(mime_types))

s = Service(GeckoDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=s, options=options)

driver.get("https://chartink.com/screener/close-below-bb-205")
WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/button[3]"))).click()
```

please let me know what is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1):

To download a file using Selenium in Python within a specified directory you need to tweak the following [`about:config`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries) entries:

[image: browser_download_dir]

---

### Solution

So an working solution can be to create a *FirefoxProfile* and then create a new directory to later download the files in it as follows:

```
newpath = 'C:\\home\\vivvin\\shKLSE'
if not os.path.exists(newpath):
    os.makedirs(newpath)    

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir",newpath);
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2);
```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of detailed discussion in:

- [Downloading file through Selenium Webdriver in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44342352/downloading-file-through-selenium-webdriver-in-python/44342891#44342891)
- [Python: Unable to download with selenium in webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44072022/python-unable-to-download-with-selenium-in-webpage/44196146#44196146)

Comment: How to use this profile in "driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=s)"